# How to make a spinner inside a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, spinner

I'm developing a small app that needs multiple tabs, each with different data inputs, all was going ok using fragments, one of these inputs must be made in the form of a spinner, but doing so results in "Cannot solve symbol" on 'parent' and 'position', also 'createFromResource (android.content.Context, int, int)' in 'android.widget.ArrayAdapter' cannot be applied to '(com.example.sinalt2.fragment2, int, int)', any way the code is here, any help is appreciated.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2, container, false);

        Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.documento, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        String text = parent.getItemPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment2">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Nome *" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Digite seu nome"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:minHeight="48dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Tipo de documento *" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="260dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:entries="@array/documento"
        android:minHeight="48dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="66dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Nº Documento *" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:minHeight="48dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="102dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Telefone *" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPhone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="176dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:minHeight="48dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="114dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="245dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="E-mail *" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextEmailAddress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="226dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:minHeight="48dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Município/UF *" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adapt the code inside the `onCreateView` as follows as the return type of `onCreateView` is View. Am also assuming that the spinner is inside the `fragment_fragment2` layout.

Also for `ArrayAdapter.createFromResource` you need to pass context. Since you are in a fragment `this` refers to `Fragment`. Hence you need to pass `getAcitvity()`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2, container, false);

    Spinner spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter =  ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),R.array.documento, 
    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    return view;
}
```

Update:
You also need to adapt the code inside the `onItemSelected`

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
    String text = parent.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the error wasn't fixed, it still can't solve the symbols of "parent" and "position", and keeps "createFromResource(android.content.Context, int, int)' in 'android.widget.ArrayAdapter' cannot be applied to '(com.example.sinalt2.fragment2, int, int)" on line 7.

Comment: @LucasdaCostaSilva Can you please add your layout file `fragment_fragment2`?

Comment: @LucasdaCostaSilva I have updated the answer. Please check if it works.

Comment: Added the full fragment_fragment2 code, it solves the bigger problem, but the "Cannot solve symbol" on 'parent' and 'position' stays.

Comment: @LucasdaCostaSilva I have updated the solution to add `onItemSelected`. Let me know if its working. Thanks

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks.